# Any auto-suggestion for try/catch C# in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, try-catch

I understand `try/catch` and their usage and tried some answers on the similar questions but they are not what I am looking for.

In JAVA, it is quite easy for developers to know where should you add `try` and `catch` because most IDE suggests it.

Is there any way to enable such auto-suggestion of `try/catch` with C# in VS? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a neat Roslyn extension :)

Comment: You may need to VA for visual studio